# C++: question on placement new in a union using Stroustrup example

Tags: c++

I'm using the following example from Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed. Page 218.  My question is regarding the destructor.

Questions:
How does placement `new(&s) string{ss}` allocate room for the new string when it's my understanding that union size is fixed to the largest member?  Is `string s` not a 0 element string?  If so, how does the placement new create a larger string if there is not enough space in the union?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Entry2 { // two alternative representations represented as a union
private:
    enum class Tag { number, text };
    Tag type; // discriminant
    union { // representation
        int i;
        string s; // string has default constructor, copy operations, and destructor
    };
public:
    struct Bad_entry { }; // used for exceptions
    string name;
    Entry2(int n) : type{Tag::number}, i{n} { };
    Entry2(string ss) : type{Tag::number} { new(&s) string{ss}; };
    ~Entry2();
    Entry2& operator=(const Entry2&); Entry2(const Entry2&);
// ...
    int number() const; string text() const;
    void set_number(int n);
    void set_text(const string&); // ...
};

Entry2::~Entry2()
{
    if (type==Tag::text)
        s.~string();
}

int Entry2::number() const
{
    if (type!=Tag::number) throw Bad_entry{};
    return i;
}

string Entry2::text() const
{
    if (type!=Tag::text) throw Bad_entry{};
    return s;
}

void Entry2::set_number(int n)
{
    if (type==Tag::text) {
        s.~string(); 
        type = Tag::number;
    }
    i = n;
}

void Entry2::set_text(const string& ss)
{
    if (type==Tag::text)
        s = ss;
    else {
        new(&s) string{ss};
        type = Tag::text;
    }
}

Entry2& Entry2::operator=(const Entry2& e)
{
    if (type==Tag::text && e.type==Tag::text) {
        s = e.s; // usual string assignment
        return *this;
    }

    if (type==Tag::text)
        s.~string(); // explicit destroy (§11.2.4)

    switch (e.type) {
    case Tag::number:
        i = e.i;
        break;
    case Tag::text:
        new(&s) string{e.s};
        type = e.type;
    }

    return *this;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Entry2 e0(0);

    cout << e0.number() << endl;
    try {
        e0.text();
    } catch (...) {
        cout << "caught except" << endl;
    }

    e0.set_text("abcd");
    cout << e0.text() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the destructor should not always do this. Remember that in a `union`, only one of the fields is actually active at any one time. If the `std::string` member of the `union` isn't active, then calling its destructor would be a Bad Thing (cause undefined behavior) because there wasn't a string there to destroy. Instead, we instead only call the destructor on that `std::string` member if at some previous point in time we activated the `std::string` there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think I'm confused on when `Entry2 e0("abc")` is called, when does the constructor for `string s` get invoked?  What is in that `union` size wise?  Also, how placement new `new(&s) string{ss}` allocates room for the new string because I thought union's were sized fixed?

Comment: Placement new is different from the regular new operator. Placement new means “here’s a memory address, and I promise it has enough space to hold the object I’m asking you to build and is properly aligned, so please make the object there.” No new memory is actually allocated. Think of it like telling a construction crew to build a building in a vacant lot you already own. In this case, the memory is already reserved for the string through the union, and we’re just saying “please turn that memory into a string.”